# Tensorflow - Implementing Max Pooling Layer following ConvLSTM3D layer

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm

Tensorflow - Max Pooling layer following 3D ConvLSTM layer

Hello!
I'm trying to implement a tensorflow.keras.layers.ConvLSTM3D algorithm, that follow by a Batch Normalisation and Max Pooling 3D.

However, when I found that when the output from Batch Normalisation layer is passed to the Pooling layer, there's an extra dimension (depth) that are presence. And I couldn't find a Max Pooling 4D layer.
Is there anyway that I could implement Max Pooling to ConvLSTM3D layer?

Thanks!

Input & Target: (samples, time, rows, cols, depth, channels)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ConvLSTM3D

#Simplified 1 layer ConvLSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM3D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same', data_format='channels_last', return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3,3,3) ,padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x=source_da, y=target_da)
```

And the error is

`Input 0 of layer "max_pooling3d_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=6. Full shape received: (None, 10, 10, 10, 2, 32)`

Comment: Hi @Cornelius, Please try by removing the `return_sequences=true` from ConvLSTM3d layer to match with required input_shape in MaxPooling3D layer.